# Extended Weibull-Cox model survival function

Tags: survival, cox-model, weibull-distribution, time-varying-covariate, proportional-hazards

I'm reading an article where the authors use an extended Cox-Weibull hazard model with time-varying covariates to model survival time of an individual. This individual is allowed to start at week $m$, and covariates are available at weekly granularity.

Assuming the hazard is represented as $\lambda\left(t ; Z(t)\right)=\lambda_0(t) e^{\beta^\top Z(t)}$, where the baseline is Weibull, they provide an expression for the probability an individual survives at least $m^\prime-m$ weeks, given they started at week $m$, through $$\tag{1} S(m^\prime-m|m)=\exp(-\lambda B(m,m^\prime))$$ where
$$
B(m,m^\prime)=\sum_{i=m+1}^{m^\prime}[(i-m)^c-(i-m-1)^c]\exp(\beta^\top Z(i)).
$$
I'm having trouble justifying expression (1), however, and feel it should follow from the relation between survival and hazard functions, namely
$$
S(m^\prime -m|m)=\exp\left(-\int_0^{m^\prime -m} \exp (\beta^\top Z(u)) \lambda_0(u)~\mathrm  d u\right).
$$
Using the fact the covariates $Z(t)$ are a step function, as they change only at the start of each week, I feel as if I can calculate what I'm after through something like
$$
\exp\left(-\left[\exp (\beta^\top Z(0)) \int_0^{1} \lambda_0(u) ~\mathrm d u+\ldots+\exp(\beta^\top Z(m^\prime-m-1)) \int_{m^\prime-m-1}^{m^\prime-m} \lambda_0(u) ~\mathrm d u\right]\right),
$$
but it doesn't seem like this will correspond to the expression in the paper.

Comment: Can you be explicit with how the Weibull is parameterized please?

Comment: I should have specified that, but for this Weibull parameterization, the hazard is $h(x|k,b)=bkx^{k-1}$, with a CDF of $1-e^{-bx^k}$

Answer (score 2):

The authors may be expressing that if an individual starts at week $m$ then they have *survived* up until week $m$, that is, they have the survival function $S(t | m) = P(T \ge t | T \ge m)$. This conditional survival function can be simplified to look like: $S(t | m) = \frac{S(t)} {S(m)}$. Their expression looks like this ratio.

Comment: I thought about this as well. I might be naive, but this felt wrong to me because it's not that the individual survived until week $m$, but rather they were born at that time. Are they equivalent?

Comment: Typically the time variable in survival analysis is not an absolute time, but a measure of duration. So it's strange to say they were _born_ at time $m$, normally you would say they were born at time 0, and record from there. However, it sounds like subjects could _enter_ study at week $m$, which would imply survival between time 0 and time m. This is called _late entry_ in the literature.

Comment: I see, this is very helpful. In this case, I worded it as born because these individuals weren't yet added to the population until time $m$, so it feels weird to condition upon survival time from 0 to $m$ in this case